# Terraform Cluster Logging Forwarder, from ARO to Azure

Tags: azure, logging, terraform, forwarding, aro

Is there a way to use Cluster Logging Forwarder to send audit log data from an ARO cluster to a Log Analytics Workspace in Azure using Terraform please.

So far I tried following these guides https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/logging/cluster-logging-external.html#cluster-logging-collector-log-forward-fluentd_cluster-logging-external and https://mobb.ninja/docs/aro/clf-to-azure/.
I thought there would be a terraform module for this but if there is one I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

The Log Analytics workspace for Red Hat Cluster can be configured using Terraform.

> I thought there would be a terraform module for this but if there is one I can't find it

Yes, this is possible with Terraform because it is also integrated with the many Azure resources that enable the logs from the ARO Cluster Creation and send them to the Log Analytics Workspace.

It is recommended to enable the SSO and MFA if the cluster is publicly available.

Here is the blog [tutorial](https://medium.com/uleap/azure-red-hat-openshift-terraformization-f4d58bbc84fe) to create # Azure Red Hat OpenShift cluster along with log analytics configuration, given by @*AymenAbdelwahed*.

Pre-requisite will be of configure RedHat.

```
1. Configure Azure CLI
2. Terraform version is >=0.12
```

upon configuration, please run

```
terraform init --upgrade
terrraform plan
terraform apply -var-file <*.tfvar>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this is asking for

`resource "null_resource" "updateAppRegistration" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOC
      az ad app update --id ${var.aro_aadClientId} --reply-urls "https://$(az openshift show -n ${var.aro_name}  -g ${var.aro_resource_group_name} --query publicHostname -o tsv)/oauth2callback/Azure%20AD"
    EOC
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
  }
   depends_on = [
     azurerm_template_deployment.azure-arocluster
   ]
}`

Comment: Hi Eliew, apologize for delay response.  Above is an example of a command-line execution to update an Azure Enterprise application. with your current client ID and update existing Azure resources for which you have partial access.